# AWS EC2 Apache port 80 closed intermittently

Tags: apache-http-server, webserver, port, http, amazon-ec2

I am having website which is running on AWS EC2 Ubuntu - Apache2 - PHP.
The website was working pretty fine and all of sudden it became unresponsive. Following are things I have checked.

1. Apache - running
2. Error Log - No error log
3. Disk Space - available

After certain check I got to know that my port 80 and 443 are showing closed by port check. Here are the checks I have done:

1. Security Group - Port 80 is open from anywhere.
2. UFW status - port 80 is there. Apache is having full access
3. The app running on port 80 is Apache only.
4. Apache restrart - not worked
5. EC2 restart - Not worked
6. Apache Re-installed - Not worked.

The strangest thing happened is: I created an image of the same EC2, I created another EC2 instance using that image and port 80 is open there.

I have the old EC2 stand there with port closed. Can someone please guide me what am I missing to check. Whether something similar happened to anyone. What can be the issue?

---

**Update**: I tried installing NGINX and stopped apache - it opened port 80, when I stopped NGINX and restart apache - port 80 gets closed again. I came to the conclusion that Apache could not access the port 80.